# Magento 2.2 Layered Navigation Category Page issue

Tags: magento2.2, layered-navigation, navigation

Thank you for taking time to read this:

We have customised our theme to show Category images on Category Pages – and also Category Banners. All this is controlled form the Category Settings from ADMIN backend. Predicament: see attached diagram 1

[image]

In order for the Category Images to show need Display setting as: Block

Doing this means the Ajax Layered Navigation Filters don’t work same page is reloaded.

In order for Ajax Layered Navigation Filters to work Display Setting must be : Products Only

Doing this doesn’t show the Category Images and Banners

If we select the Third Option for Display Setting: Static Block and Products  - this solves both things i.e. category images and banners are displayed AND Ajax filters work BUT the filter results are showing on the bottom below the Category Images Content – which is not good or practical as no one will notice them there after applying filters.

Question:

Is it possible to show the filtered results on same page but without the Category Images and Banner? So once the user selects any filter the Category Images and Banners no longer show and only the products show which are relevant to the filter or filters applied in the Ajax Layered Navigation-

A perfect working example from a website can be seen here

https://www.nisbets.co.uk/cleaning-and-hygiene/_/a33-1

Any ideas on how can this be achieved.

We currently have Amasty improved layered Navigation but we have tried others too but issue is stil same

Thank You